# Vaadin 6.8.9 table improperly display

Tags: vaadin, vaadin6

I'm using Vaadin 6.8.9. Recently, I come across a issue. The table doesn't present properly as follow image. The headers are not able to appear. I tried to re-install tomcat7,and compile widgets couple times. The issue is still there. The issue only occur on my machine. I couldn't figure out the problem. 
Could anybody have this issue ever? Give me some clues. Thanks very much.

[image: Vaadin 6.8.9 table]

Comment: What do you mean by "issue only occur on my machine"?

Comment: As you seen, there is no header displayed. Actually, I setup  header to display. The same code running on anther machine has no problem at all.

Comment: Have you tried with another browser on your maschine? Perhaps you have some addons installed which cause the problem

Comment: I'd agree to first test in another browser, as André suggested. If it works, then it seems to be a browser cache issue, if it doesn't then it might be the widgetset compilation doesn't go cleanly through and I'd suggest nuke all build folders, delete old widgetset, clear all caches etc.

Another test is to have it deployed on your computer but contact your server from the other computer where it works.

Comment: Hard refresh css. Restart computer/eclipse. Check another browser or/and private mode.

Comment: I manually clean everything. The problem is still there.